# Puntero desvaneciéndose

Tags: c, punteros

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tlista tlista;

struct tlista {
  tlista *back;
  char *valor;
  tlista *go;
};

tlista* getPunteros(int index, tlista *back);

int main() {
  tlista tmp;
  // creas el puntero, que tendra los valores y los demas punteros
  // como necesitas la siguiente lista para el go, se implementa con un algoritmo recursivo
  tlista *punteros = getPunteros(1, NULL), *puntero;

  printf("%s %s %s\n", punteros->valor, (punteros->go)->valor, ((punteros->go)->go)->valor);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}

tlista* getPunteros(int index, tlista *back) {
  char *frase1 = "Hola,", *frase2 = "Â¿que", *frase3 = "tal?";
  tlista *punteros;
  tlista lista;

  punteros = &lista;
  lista.back = back;
  if (index == 1) lista.valor = frase1;
  else if (index == 2) lista.valor = frase2;
  else lista.valor = frase3;

  lista.go = NULL;
  if (index < 3) lista.go = getPunteros(index + 1, punteros);

  return punteros;
}
```

El **problema** está en el `printf` de `((punteros->go)->go)->valor`, que solo puede llamarse una vez (puede comprobarse añadiendo el mismo `printf` justo debajo). Luego, `(punteros->go)->go` pasa a valer `NULL`.

¿Alguien puede decirme que sucede?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tlista* getPunteros(int index, tlista *back) 
  tlista lista;      // variable local

  punteros = &lista; // puntero apuntando a variable local

  return punteros;   // variable local muere
}
```

El problema puede resumirse en los comentarios que ves en el código que te he puesto.

`lista` es una variable local, luego su vida está limitada a la función. En cuanto la ejecución abandona la función la memoria asignada a dicha variable (en la pila del programa) deja de estar reservada y puede ser utilizada por cualquier otra variable.

Así pues, el puntero que devuelves no es válido ya que no apunta a una dirección de memoria válida.

La solución es tan simple como usar memoria dinámica:

```
tlista* getPunteros(int index, tlista *back) 
  punteros = (tlista*)malloc(sizeof(tlista);

  // Haces lo que quieras con 'punteros'

  return punteros;
}

int main()
{
  tlista * ptr = getPunteros(/* ... */);

  // ...

  while( ptr )
  {
    tlista* temp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->go;
    free(temp);  // liberamos la memoria
  }
}
```